# echo all images target folder referenced from sql database in a table

Tags: php

**this is what i have but failing to see why only one image shows and the rest of the table is broken**

```
  echo "<table id='customers'>"; // start a table tag in the HTML
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo "<tr><th><b>Logo:</b></th>
    <th><b>Details: </b></th>
    <th><b>id: </b></th>
    <th><b>Support: </b></th>
    <th><b>Amount: </b></th>
    <th><b>Paid: </b></th>
    <th><b>Created: </b></th></tr>
    <tr><th><img src=/images/" . $row["image"]. " " . "style='width:128px; height:128px'/></th>
    <th>" . $row["image_text"]. " " . "</th>
    <th>" . $row["id"]. " " . "</th>
    <th>" . $row["support"]. " " . "</th>
    <th>" . $row["Amount"]. " " . "</th>
    <th>" . $row["Paid"]. " " . "</th>
    <th>" . $row["created"]."</th></tr><br>";
```

echo ""; //Close the table in HTML

[page here](http://netradiocoalition.com/pipe.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you see the html code of the page this is the result:

```
…
<img src=/images/13_streamspinner.png style='width:128px; height:128px'/>
…
```

It seems you've been confusing the quotes. You forgot some tips.

**Try this:**

```
echo "<table id='customers'>"; // start a table tag in the HTML
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo '<tr><th><b>Logo:</b></th>
          <th><b>Details:</b></th>
          <th><b>id:</b></th>
          <th><b>Support:</b></th>
          <th><b>Amount:</b></th>
          <th><b>Paid:</b></th>
          <th><b>Created:</b></th></tr>
          <tr><td><img src="/images/' .$row["image"]. '" style="width:128px; height:128px;"/></td>
          <td>'.$row["image_text"].'</td>
          <th>'.$row["id"].'</td>
          <td>'.$row["support"].'</td>
          <td>'.$row["Amount"].'</td>
          <td>'.$row["Paid"].'</td>
          <td>'.$row["created"].'</td></tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

**Update:**
I had not noticed as pointed out by lewisnewson, that you actually used `<th>` each time instead of `<td>`. I have updated my answer including the `while` loop and the closing of the table.

Answer (score 0):

You have some missing quotes, as suggested in Yeti's answer but looking at the source code of that page, you are including `</table>` on each iteration of your while loop. Try something like this:

```
// Open the table here
echo "<table id='customers'>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  // Now loop through each element
  echo '<tr><th><b>Logo:</b></th>
  <th><b>Details:</b></th>
  <th><b>id:</b></th>
  <th><b>Support:</b></th>
  <th><b>Amount:</b></th>
  <th><b>Paid:</b></th>
  <th><b>Created:</b></th></tr>
  <tr><td><img src="/images/' .$row["image"]. '" style="width:128px; height:128px;"/></td>
  <td>'.$row["image_text"].'</td>
  <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
  <td>'.$row["support"].'</td>
  <td>'.$row["Amount"].'</td>
  <td>'.$row["Paid"].'</td>
  <td>'.$row["created"].'</td></tr><br>';
}
// Close the table after the loop is complete
echo '</table>';
```

**Note:** You'll see i've moved some of your `th` tags around. You are using `th` tags which are normally reserved for table headings to output your data. I'd move your data items into `td` tags. More information on table structure can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you gentleman from your comments I was able to solve my issues, as below.**

```
    <?php
    $servername = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";

// Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT id, image, image_text, support, Amount, Paid, created  FROM 
    images";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo "<table id='customers'>"; // start a table tag in the HTML
    echo "<tr><th><b>Logo:</b></th>
        <th><b>Details: </b></th>
        <th><b>id: </b></th>
        <th><b>Support: </b></th>
        <th><b>Amount: </b></th>
        <th><b>Paid: </b></th>
        <th><b>Created: </b></th></tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


        echo "<tr><th><img src=/images/" . $row["image"]. " " . 
    "style='width:128px; height:128px'/></th>
        <th>" . $row["image_text"]. " " . "</th>
        <th>" . $row["id"]. " " . "</th>
        <th>" . $row["support"]. " " . "</th>
        <th>" . $row["Amount"]. " " . "</th>
        <th>" . $row["Paid"]. " " . "</th>
        <th>" . $row["created"]."</th></tr><br>";
    }
    echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML  

// <tr><th>" . $row["image"]. " " . "</th>


    } else {
    echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```